# Loop through a list of URLs and retain only those that exist

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, purrr

I am in a situation where I need to check 1000s of URLs to see if they exist, and retain the urls in an object if they exist (i am calling it "exist") and store those that don't in another object ("not exist").

```
urls <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_in_",1990:2020)

for(i in seq_along(urls)){
     exist <- keep(urls[i], http_error(urls[i]))
     not_exist <- discard(urls[i], httpe_error(url[i])
}
```

I want to avoid using the loop and just stick to the purrr functions, I tried doing

```
exists <- map(urls,http_error)
```

But this just returns true/False.

My eventual goal is to create a table with two columns titled "exists" and "not exists" as follows:

```
\begin{table}[] \begin{tabular}{lll} Exists & Not Exists &  \\ 
URL    &  URL &  \\ 
URL    & URL  &  \\ 
URL    & URL  &  \\ 
URL    &      &  \\
URL    &      &  \\ 
URL    &      &  
\end{tabular} \end{table}
```

Comment: If your `map` try returns TRUE FALSE, isn't that good? `urls_exist = urls[exists]`, `urls_not_exist = urls[!exists]`?

Comment: *"My eventual goal is to create a table with two columns titled "exists" and "not exists""* this seems like a bad idea. I assume by "table" you mean data frame? Data frames need to be *rectangular* - every column has the same number of rows. Unless  exactly half the urls exist and half don't exist, they won't fit very well like you describe. A two column data frame with one column for the URL and one column `exists` showing `TRUE` or `FALSE` seems more useful: `data.frame(urls, exists)`

Comment: I apologise for the confusion, by eventual goal i mean a LaTeX table

Comment: Do you have sample code for a ragged (non-rectangular) LaTeX table that you're trying to use?

Comment: It is an ugly table, but here you go:
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Exists                                                                      & Not Exists                                                                                               &  \\
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List\_of\_countries\_by\_population\_in\_2000 & {\color[HTML]{0563C1} {ur}} &  \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{url}                                                                                        &  \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{url here}   & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: Better formatted LaTeX code here:It is an ugly table, but here you go:
`\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Exists & Not Exists                       &  \\
URL    & {\color[HTML]{0563C1} {\ul URL}} &  \\
URL    & URL                              &  \\
URL    & URL                              &  \\
URL    &                                  &  \\
URL    &                                  &  \\
URL    &                                  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}`

Comment: Edit it into your question - no sense putting it in comments with bad formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
correct_urls <- purrr::keep(urls, ~!httr::http_error(.x))
incorrect_urls <- purrr::keep(urls, ~httr::http_error(.x))
```

Or other option if you don't want to call the http_error twice

```
url_error <- purrr::map_lgl(urls, httr::http_error)
incorrect_urls <- urls[url_error]
correct_urls <- urls[!url_error]
```

Then you can put those urls in the LaTeX table

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a rather clunky solution, it works but scores very low on efficiency and elegance.

```
urls <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_in_",1990:2020)
library(httr)

safe_url_logical <- map(urls, http_error)

temp <- cbind(unlist(safe_url_logical), unlist(urls))

colnames(temp) <- c("logical","url")
temp <- as.data.frame(temp)

safe_urls <- temp %>% 
     dplyr::filter(logical=="FALSE")
dead_urls <- temp %>% 
     dplyr::filter(logical=="TRUE")
```