# Find each gameId by looping through a very large list of URLs and keeping those that exist

Tags: r, purrr, httr, rcurl

I am trying to obtain a list of all `gameId`'s for each boxscore url from here:

https://www.espn.com/nhl/boxscore/_/gameId/

Each URL ends with a specific `gameID`, e.g.

https://www.espn.com/nhl/boxscore/_/gameId/4014559236

The problem I have is that I don't know the range or numbers of all of the `gameId`s. For the start of the 2023-2024 season, they appear to start with `4014559236` and increment by 1. But for, say the start of the 2007-2008 season, they begin with `271009021`.

I would like to get them from as far back as possible.

I used the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648452/loop-through-a-list-of-urls-and-retain-only-those-that-exist), which allows me to specify some `gameId`s, check if the URL exists and if it does, output the `gameId`.

My code here just uses three `gameId`s from the start of the 2023-2024 season:

```
library(httr)
library(purrr)
library(RCurl)

urls <- paste0("https://www.espn.com/nhl/boxscore/_/gameId/",4014559236:4014559240)

safe_url_logical <- map(urls, http_error)
temp <- cbind(unlist(safe_url_logical), unlist(urls))
colnames(temp) <- c("logical","url")
temp <- as.data.frame(temp)
safe_urls <- temp %>% 
  dplyr::filter(logical=="FALSE")
dead_urls <- temp %>% 
  dplyr::filter(logical=="TRUE")

df_exist <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(safe_urls)) {
  url <- as.character(safe_urls$url[i])
  exist <- url.exists(url)
  df_exist <- rbind(df_exist, url)
}

urls = df_exist

game_ids = sub('.*\\/', '', urls)
print(game_ids)
[1] "401559238" "401559239" "401559240"
```

But if I was to specify from say `271009021` to `4014559236`, this is an extremely large amount of numbers and URLs to check.

Is there an alternate way which can gain speed and efficiency?

I would also like to obtain the date of each game, altough I haven't been able to find that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start at each teams schedule for each year.  For example: https://www.espn.com/nhl/team/schedule/_/name/ana/season/2022 (Ducks for 2022-23 season) and extract out the gameID from the "result" column.

Here is the code for that:

```
url <- "https://www.espn.com/nhl/team/schedule/_/name/ana/season/2022"
page <- read_html(url)

#get the main table
schedule <- page %>% html_elements("table") 

#now take the each row, take the third column and find the "a" subnode
# from that subnode extract the link to the game stats
linkstogames <- schedule %>% html_elements(xpath = ".//tr //td[3] //a") %>%
                    html_attr("href")


 [1] "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349148" "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349152"
 [3] "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349170" "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349182"
 [5] "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349193" "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349208"
 [7] "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349228" "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349240"
 [9] "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349249" "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349262"
[11] "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349275" "https://www.espn.com/nhl/game/_/gameId/401349293
```

Comment: that is a good place to start. I will give that a try.